# How to take kmllayer and make a menu out of items with listensers?

Tags: javascript, html, kml

I have a map with a kmllayer that is added:

```
    ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.npd.no/engelsk/cwi/pbl/en/aFactGlobe/disc/ActivityStatus_Producing_labels.kml');
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

How do I:

1. Parse the data to make a menu with all the producing fields (info in kml file)
2. Add a click listener to each field in the menu so a popup window comes up (I want to do the same as if marker itself was clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KmlLayer doesn't allow access to the objects displayed.  You can create a sidebar using a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)).

[Example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_icon_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/visualisationmagazine_com_lacreativemap_kml.xml)

One disadvantage of using a third-party KML parser is that you lose the advantage of having the data rendered as tiles, so for complex KML the performance won't be as good.

Another option is to import your kml into FusionTables.

[Example using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)